# How to Clip Text in a TTreeview

Tags: delphi

The Delphi IDE Locals window clips the names of the local variables if the Name column is too narrow like this:

[image]

I would like to do the same thing in my program.  At present I am using a TMS THTMLTreeList and the results I am getting look like this:

[image]

Is it possible to clip the text like the IDE does?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: for TMS - subscribe to their support, else study the demo and use owner-draw treeview

Comment: Although I did post on the TMS forum before posting here, it had been some time without a response.  I was hoping for some help here because a lot of the TMS stuff just adds functionality to the components that come stock with Delphi.  It appears in this case, it looks like they may have blocked the firing of one of the events.  Maybe they have another way to make it work.  I reposted on TMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with a TMS treeview, but for the standard TTreeView you would have to owner-draw the text manually, then you can clip it however you want. I forget the name of it right now, but the RTL does have a function that draws text onto a TCanvas with a user-specified clipping width that draws the ellipses for you.

Comment: `DrawText` with `DT_END_ELLIPSIS`

Comment: That's not the function I was thinking of. That is a Win32 API function. There is a function in the RTL/VCL that takes a TCanvas as a parameter. I'll have to look it up when I get a chance.

Comment: The RTL equivalent you are thinking of is `TCanvas.TextRect`.

Comment: No, that is not the one, either. The one I am thinking of is a standalone function that takes a TCanvas, a String, and a pixel width as parameters.

Comment: That's not what's wanted here. That's for file names. Plus I'd always prefer the function that ships with Windows.

Comment: David is right.  DrawText is what I am looking for.  Thanks for your input though Remy.

Comment: I finally tried this with a standard TTreeList.  It is clipping, although it is not putting the ellipsis on the end.  This is progress, though and I will see what else I can find out about it.  I don't know how the TMS control is supposed to work or if it is not completely functional.  I repeated the question on the TMS forum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function AbbrText(const AText : string; ACanvas : TCanvas; const AMaxWidthPixels : Integer) : string;
begin
  Result := AText;
  if ACanvas.TextWidth(Result) > AMaxWidthPixels do
    begin
      while (Length(Result) <> 0) and (ACanvas.TextWidth(Result + '...') > AMaxWidthPixels) do
        SetLength(Result, Length(Result) - 1);
      if Result <> '' then
        Result := Result + '...';
    end;
end;
```

I won't argue this is the most efficient code, but it should do what you need it to do.  Pass your text and the THTMLTreeList canvas to the function and you'll get back the text that will fit into AMaxWidthPixels.  If there isn't even enough room for the ellipsis then it will return an empty string.

Comment: This is a nice answer because it suggests an approach that may be useful in other situations.  However, the DrawText function seems to be designed specifically for the present case.

Comment: Well... my thought was that you would use this function result in a call to DrawText() or whatever method you want to use to actually draw the text.  This would just determine what part of the string (or all of it) would fit within the area you want to use.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  It is my impression that DrawText has enough information to determine where to clip the string and add the ellipsis.  I am hoping that I will get some help with on why the OnCustomDrawItem event is not firing or how to actually make use of DrawText.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input.  I'm guessing that DrawText is what I am looking for.  The TMS Treelist seems to be pretty much the standard control with features for adding some HTML formatting to the text which might come in handy as this little project develops.

I'm afraid this is going to sound really lame, but I am not getting a hit on my event handler and I don't know why.  I set this up to override the event handler for OnCustomDrawItem:

```
procedure TForm1.trXMLCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView; Node: TTreeNode;
  State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var hContext: HDC;
    s: PChar;
    iLength: Integer;
    uRect: TRect;
begin
  DefaultDraw := False;
  hContext := trXML.Canvas.Handle;
  s := PChar(Node.Text);
  iLength := Length(Node.Text);
  uRect := Node.DisplayRect(True);
  DrawText(hContext, s, iLength, uRect, DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
end;
```

It seems to me that this event should fire whenever a node needs to be redrawn.  I am not seeing it fire when the tree is first loaded and also not when I change the size of the columns so that there is more or less overwriting.  I don't know why there is no CustomDraw boolean property for this control, but I am sure that it is just something I am missing.  If you have time, I would very much appreciate a little instruction in doing this correctly.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. OnCustomDrawItem should be called when there's a handler for it.

Comment: Is the handler actually assigned to the event?

Comment: Yes.  I checked it several times.  It's odd.  I have always had great results with TMS but sometimes the appropriate process is not documented.