# How to Clip Text in a TTreeview (Continued)

Tags: delphi

I have taken the advice, or at least I think I have, that I got in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451667/how-to-clip-text-in-a-ttreeview).
To summarize, I replaced the THTMLTreeList from TMS with a TTreeList and made two columns in it.  I set the first column to 150 pixels and I overrode the AdvancedCustomDrawItem event with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.trXMLAdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
  var PaintImages, DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var hContext: HDC;
    s: PChar;
    iLength: Integer;
    uRect: TRect;
begin
  DefaultDraw := False;
  hContext := trXML.Canvas.Handle;
  s := PChar(Node.Text);
  iLength := Length(Node.Text);
  uRect := Node.DisplayRect(True);
  DrawText(hContext, s, iLength, uRect, DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
end;
```

I got the result I expected, that is, when I draw the tree, the text in the first column is clipped.  And when I change the size of the first column, the text is appropriately clipped.  But when the TreeList is not wide enough and has a scroll bar on the bottom and I scroll to the right, the text now extends into the second column by the same amount as the scroll bar has been moved.  It's like the text is drawn relative to the client area of the TreeList rather than the partially hidden first column so it always extends 150 pixels into the TreeList.

It seems to me that I am using the wrong thing for the device context handle or the TRect but I do very little graphic type programming so I don't know what to change.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the sender's handle?

Comment: By that I mean Sender.Handle instead of Sender.Canvas.Handle.

Comment: I don't know.  That might be right.  OK.  I tried it.  I got the same result.  If you drop a TTreeList on a form and override its AdvancedCustomDrawItem event with the code above, you will see what I mean.  This is a bit of a black box to me so I will try anything, but that did not fix it.

Comment: @Jerry: `Sender.Handle` is an `HWND`, but `DrawText()` needs an `HDC` instead. `Sender.Canvas.Handle` would be more appropriate. In this case, `Sender` and `trXML` are the same object.

Comment: @jrodenhi: what you describe sounds like the `TRect` contains the wronf coordinates when the tree has been scrolled.

Comment: @Remy: Thanks for staying with me on this.  I thought the same thing you did.  So I put a break point inside the event handler and watched when the column was scrolled far to the right.  The TRect points vary with the text.  When the text is 'ReturnData', the points are (-45, 0, 18, 16), and when the text is 'ContentLocation;Unique-identifier444;', points are (-26, 16, 165, 32).  The first one is contained entirely in the first column and the second one does not.  I would expect the second one to have a rectangle where the difference between the two x values is 150.

Comment: @jrodenhi: keep in mind that TreeView controls do not natively support columns at the OS layer. That is accomplished using owner-drawing techniques, which the DisplayRect() method knows nothing about. The TRect.Left value is always relative to the top-left corner of the client area, so you need to subtract that offset from your column width to determine how much space is available for that node to reach the right-side boundary of the column, and then clip the TRect accordingly before then drawing the text. That way, the text will not carry into the second column. I will post an example.

Comment: @Remy: Sorry.  Asynchronous posting.  It looks like the left side of the rectangle might equal the graphic branch of the tree.  So the first item 'ReturnData' is at -45 because it is a root node.  The second item 'ContentLocation;Unique-identifier444;' is at -26 because it is a child of a root node.  The indent is set at 19 so all that adds up.  You would think then, that setting the TRect.right to the TRect.Left + trXML.Columns[0].Width would get the right clipping, but it doesn't.  It's a puzzle to me.

Comment: @jrodenhi: are you using an up-to-date version of TMS? I just checked TMS's source code and TTreeList already uses the DT_END_ELLIPSIS flag and does per-column clipping of text when DefaultDraw=True. I'm using 4.6.0.3 myself.

Comment: @Remy: BINGO.  Setting DefaultDraw = True made it work.  On a guess, I set it to False some time ago.  I stopped looking at that when I was trying to get the THTMLTreeList to fire this event at all.  Thank you for pointing this out.  If you moved your comment to a response, I would gladly accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked TMS's source code and
`TTreeList` already uses the `DT_END_ELLIPSIS` flag
and does per-column clipping of drawn text when the `DefaultDraw` parameter is set to `True`, so you don't need to draw the text yourself manually.

Comment: +1 I agree on the excellent perseverance.  I know there isn't an unlimited supply of that stuff going around and I am sorry to have used so much of it.